# Samsung лаги с загрузкой страницы на которой есть  js

Tags: android, javascript, webview, samsung

Доброго времени суток.
Немного странный вопрос -кто сталкивался с лагами samsung при загрузке в webview html страницы с js ? 
У меня под рукой нет sumsung, но у посредника именно он, при загрузке страницы если перевернуть телефон приложение виснет, если перед этим подвигать страницу то все в порядке. У меня на телефоне этот баг воспроизвести не удалось, и по сути его устранения никто пока не требует (да это странно, но пока все всех устраивает и есть более актуальные задачи) наткнулся в статье на следующий комментарий

> . Или случай с вебстраничкой и javascript, в котором спецом для SGS2 пришлось персонально писать костыль
>
> String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER ;
> String model = Build.MODEL ;
> if ( manufacturer.equals("samsung") && model.equals("GT-I9100") )  {
>     // код костыля
> }
>
> На других девайсах этот же код работал некорректно, а вот самсунг без него вешался.

Возможно кто то  сталкивался с подобным, не хочу оставлять этот косяк, все равно думаю к нему придется вернуться, а самсунга в моем парке устройств пока нет (
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Самсунг Самсунгу рознь...    
не на всех Самсунгах все работает одинаково...    
На моей практике тоже есть пару моментов, где один Самсунг(одна-единственная модель) вел себя абсолютно не так, как остальные Самсунги и другие телефоны.    
Думаю, придется искать-таки проблемную модель, и дебажить на ней...

Comment: с этим так раз проблемы, в крайнем случае придется все это делать удаленно ( с одной стороны пока  не требуют, с другой не дело так оставлять ... да и это пока - хочется заранее соломки подстелить